# Populate data with ratio to previous element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data which looks like this {x,y}:

```
data={{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{4,6}}
```

I need to add another column and  define it as current element divided by previous element.

This could be done like this:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i++, 
 If[i == 1, data[[i]] = Append[data[[i]], 1], 
 data[[i]] = Append[data[[i]], data[[i, 2]]/data[[i - 1, 2]]]]]
```

However, I think that in Mathematica there may be a better way to do it

What is the easiest way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Is there any rule about the first element in a new column or is it always 1?

Comment: it's always 1, since there is no previous element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Join[
    data
  , List /@ Prepend[Ratios @ data[[;; , 2]], 1]
  , 2
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Join[{AppendTo[data[[1]], 1]}, 
Table[{data[[i]][[1]], data[[i]][[2]], 
data[[i]][[2]]/data[[i - 1]][[2]]}, {i, 2, Length@data}]]
```

> {{1, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 4/3}, {3, 5, 5/4}, {4, 6, 6/5}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Flatten[Riffle[#, Ratios@Prepend[#2 & @@@ #, Last@First[#]]], 1]&@data~Partition~3
(* {{1, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 4/3}, {3, 5, 5/4}, {4, 6, 6/5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Transpose[{#1, #2, {1}~Join~Ratios[#2]} & @@ Transpose[data]]
```